# Excel - Divide One Column Vector Into Several Line Vectors

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose, column

I am currently struggling to find out how a **long** column vector in excel can be divided into several line vectors.

E.g.

```
% one long column vector
20,857
20,888
14,938
0,01
20,872
20,825
14,992
0,007
20,786
20,756
14,96
0,015
20,855
20,9
14,981
0,004
20,921
20,838
14,972
0,004
```

into

```
% several line vectors
[20,857 20,888 14,938 0,01;
20,872 20,825 14,992 0,007;
20,786 20,756 14,96 0,015;
% and so on]
```

[Depicted in a picture from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MntTC.png)

Of course I could go ahead and always copy x (e.g. x = 4) lines, right click on my destination and and choose "insert" and select "transpose" from the menu. However with an increasing length of the column vector this is a time extensive option.

Can someone come up with a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data starts from A2, in B2 enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(COLUMN(A1)+3,4)+ROW(A1)*4-3,)
```

Drag the fill handle right and then down.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A** starting at **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMNS($A:A)+4*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

and copy both downwards and to the right:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

assuming your line vector started in cell A1, you could use index for this.

Where ever you want the grid to start use the below formula, then drag across 4 cells, and then down as many as desired:

```
  =INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($D$4:D4)*4)-3+COLUMNS($D$4:D4)-1,1)
```

[image]

If your data started in A2, then replace `=INDEX($A:$A` with `=INDEX($A2:$A5000` or amend to where it may start.